# insert data into two tables using one query (phpmyadmin)

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

i have two tables: item_group and item_breakdown. I'd like to fill both tables at the same time so i decided to use stored procedures. here's what i have created so far but i get errors. i'm still new to phpmyadmin and my english is not that good so please bear with me :)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test5
(
IN item_group_desc varchar(150),
IN item_group_qty int(5),
IN item_group_uom varchar(10),
IN item_group_location varchar(50),
IN item_group_inv_by varchar(50),
IN item_group_crit_amount int(5)
)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO item_group(item_group_code,item_group_desc,categ_ID,item_group_qty,uom,location,inv_by,type,name,desc,sci_name,crit_amount)
VALUES ('asd',item_group_desc,1,item_group_qty,item_group_uom,item_group_location,item_group_inv_by,'n/a','n/a','n/a','n/a',item_group_crit_amount);
declare x int;
set x=1;
while x<=item_group_qty do
INSERT INTO item_breakdown(status,brand,expiry,item_group_ID) 
VALUES(
SELECT 
            'available',
            'n/a',
            'n/a',  
            item_group_id
FROM item_group
ORDER BY item_group_id DESC 
LIMIT 1 ***plus 1
             );
set x=x+1;
END WHILE
END//
```

i put "plus 1" there because item_group_code is Auto_increment and i'd like to use next value to be inserted on the second table.
could anyone help me and point out what im doing wrong? thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can acheive this by calling `mysql_insert_id()` or `last_insert_id()`, simply by:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

For more information: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-insert-id.html